# Construct a TM for checking if a set of parentheses are well formed

Tags: turing-machines

This was a solved example given in my textbook. When I tried to solve this, I got a different TM that was given as the solution. I tried running a sample string through my TM,  and somehow got the correct answer. 
Still the answers dont match. Please let me know if there isvsomething I've missed. 
This may sound a simple school homework but I would be grateful for any help

The one in ink is my solution
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiJX6.jpg)

This is the textbook answer.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6HY7.jpg)

Comment: What is the notation of your Turing machine? Some of your transitions don't have $\to$ arrows in them. Does the symbol $\vdash$ mean blank?

Comment: Also, which are the accept states?

Comment: Well, no wonder you got a different answer. "Design a Turing machine to do X" is essentially the same question as "Write a Java program to do X", only in a different language. You wouldn't expect to write the same Java program as your textbook's author, and you shouldn't expect to write the same Turing machine, either.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request to check an answer to an exercise with no specific concerns raised.

Comment: I asked this once already, but I'll ask again: why are we bombarded with questions about construction of specific pointless Turing machines that seem like busy-work exercises? Is this a thing in CS courses in the US?

Comment: @AndrejBauer. Unfortunately so. You can check the recommendations in the latest issue of the *Journal of Ineffective Instruction in Computer Science.* Seriously, though, I'd never assign a task like that; TM programming is even uglier than assembly language, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very important fact about Turing machines is that there may be many *equivalent* Turing machines for the same language. In other words, just because your answer and the book's answer are different *Turing machines*, they may both be correct answers. There is not just one Turing machine for any given task.

I am not sure if your Turing machine is actually correct (building a Turing machine without any errors is hard!), but if you answer the questions in my comments I can probably figure it out and update this answer. We can also try a few more input strings to check.